# Haxe plugin for Sublime Text 2

Tags: sublimetext2, haxe

Woke up today to the Haxe plugin for Sublime Text 2 having just not working. I tried removing it and installing it again, but no success. Anyone who has any ideas on how to debug this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like it got renamed from "HaXe" to "Haxe".  You can try uninstalling (Cmd-Shift-P, "Remove Package") and then reinstall (Cmd-Shift-P, "Package Manager: Install Package").

If that doesn't help, perhaps you can look at the Console (`View -> Show Console`) and look for any error messages related to Haxe and post them here...